# electron : (js) blob wav to main.js for save to disk from renderer.js

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, blob, wav

I have in preload.js:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
// Toutes les API Node.js sont disponibles dans le processus de préchargement.
// Il a la même sandbox qu'une extension Chrome.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector)
    if (element) element.innerText = text
  }

  for (const dependency of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
    replaceText(`${dependency}-version`, process.versions[dependency])
  }

})
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
"api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain",'fromparam'];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        },
        contextmenu: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["showmenu"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel,'showmenu')
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I create an 'audio/wav' Mime type blob
I do this in my index.html::

```
window.api.send("toMain", "saveAudioObjet;"+(audioDirectory+"exports/"+tableObjet[obj].id+".wav")+";"+blob)
```

I have this in main.js:
(via ipcMain.on ("toMain" ...)

```
function saveAudioObjet(dest,buf) {

 fs.writeFile(dest, 
        Buffer.from(buf), function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!')
        })
}
```

how to save this blob to disk ( dest is filePath, buf the blob) ?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the code you currently have?

Comment: the resulting file is 13 bytes while the blob is 995992 and the file is not recognized by audacity

Comment: with electron, I am unable to send an audio/wave type blob from my renderer.js to main.js to save it to disk. It's definitely a problem with the type of data transferred but I can't solve this problem.

Comment: The answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503746/save-blob-audio-on-disk-width-electron/77507428#77507428